# Redis service start on windows

Tags: windows-services, redis-cluster

Redis service is not starting on windows 10. pls help.
[image]

redis.windows-service-redis1.conf :-

```
bind 127.0.0.1
port 6379
```

command :-

```
sc create RedisM DisplayName= "RedisM" binPath= "\"redis-server.exe\" –service-install \"redis.windows-service-redis1.conf\"
```

Comment: You should run the "redis-server --service-install" command to install Redis as a service instead of trying to create the service yourself.